# Javascript: Do Array.prototype methods work on Float32 multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using a `Float32Array` for vertex positions in `Three.js`. I would like to return a new array of vertex positions starting at a random point.

```
[0...10000].slice( n, n + 100 ) // Works 

positions      = new Float32Array( amount * 3 ) 
randPositions  = positions.slice( n, n + 100 )  // Doesn't work - undefined is not a function
```

However, when I do this, it returns an error (`positions` is defined and has data)? Are `Array.prototype` methods compatible with `Float32Array`?

Comment: Try `[].slice.call(positions, n, n + 100);` (haven't tried it and it may not work)

Comment: Yes! that works. Add that as the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things that look like arrays — that have a `.length` property and numerically-indexed properties — work with the built-in Array methods, but you have to call them explicitly:

```
randPositions = [].slice.call(positions, n, n + 100);
```

That trick grabs a reference to the "slice" method from a throw-away Array instance and calls it via `.call()` to make your "positions" array be `this` inside the function.

Comment: Very clever and elegant. I am humbled.

Comment: @ForeignObject: You should be aware that the result isn't a typed array. Depending on your need, you may be better off just working with the range you need, perhaps via a wrapping object that provides methods for convenience. Or if you need an actual copy of the subset, then you may want to manually copy the data over.

Comment: @cookiemonster yes I realized that too right after I typed this in, but I had shut down my laptop and started driving across town :)